# How can I type simple underline "_" in Auctex

Tags: auctex, aquamacs, insert

I am using Auctex in Aquamacs. Everytime I type underline "_", it will show as `$_{}$` automatically which is very annoying. I am wondering how could I turn off this function. Thanks.

Comment: This (very useful, actually) feature is not enabled by default.  As explained by Gilles, this is controlled by `TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript`, you somehow set it to `t` in your init file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always insert a character literally by typing `C-q` first ([`quoted-insert`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Inserting-Text.html#Inserting-Text)).

Many “electric” characters (that's what Emacs usually calls characters whose insertion has extra effects such as inserting extra braces, reindenting, etc.) are designed to revert to a plain insertion if you pass a [numeric prefix argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html#Arguments), i.e. type `ESC 1 _` or `M-1 _` to insert one underscore. I don't know if this is the case specifically for the command you're using.

To see the effect of the `_` key, type `C-h k` ([`describe-key`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Help.html#Key-Help)) followed by `_`. That will give you a description of the command, and perhaps a way to customize it. By default, in AUCTeX, `_` runs `TeX-insert-sub-or-superscript` which just inserts a `_` unless [`TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002delectric_002dsub_002dand_002dsuperscript) is turned on, and even then it only inserts braces if already in math mode.

It turns out that you're using [cdlatex](https://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex), where `_` is bound to [`cdlatex-sub-superscript`](https://github.com/cdominik/cdlatex/blob/a0e0ad9efa3ffc918d4c23fa7db7563b1bef0dae/cdlatex.el#L768). If you want to keep using cdlatex but deactivate the electric behavior of `_`, you can remove `_` from the cdlatex keymap after the package is loaded:

```
(defun my-after-load-cdlatex ()
  (define-key cdlatex-mode-map "_" nil)
  t)
(eval-after-load "cdlatex" '(my-after-load-cdlatex))
```

You may wish to activate AUCTeX's less invasive electric `_` by setting `TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript`:

```
(setq TeX-electric-sub-and-superscript t)
```

Comment: Hi Gilles, thank you for your answer. I tries `C-h k` followed by `_`. The response is given below: 
>  _ runs the command cdlatex-sub-superscript (found in cdlatex-mode-map), which is an interactive Lisp function in 'cdlatex.el'. At this moment, `C-q _` works for me. But how could I do to keep underline bound with  brace`{}` and dollars works and only works in math environment? Thank you.

Comment: @Raymond See my updated answer.